# Oracle xQuery generate XML with namespaces

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery, xml-namespaces

In Oracle 19 I call several web services via SOAP, so I must generate XMLs like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:my="my:uriservice1">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <my:Service1>
      <Param1 xsi:type="string">Value1</Param1>
      <Param2 xsi:type="int">Value2</Param2>
    </my:Service1>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Need help to do it dynamically in xQuery.
I store namespaces and service parameters in tables so I can provide example to pass them as xQuery parameters

```
select * from XMLTable('???' passing
  'Service1' as "service",
  XMLType(cursor(with ns as
    (select 'SOAP' Service, 'xsi' Code, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' Value from dual
      union all
     select 'SOAP', 'soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' from dual
      union all
     select 'Service1', 'my', 'uriservice1' from dual)
    select * from ns)) as "ns",
  XMLType(cursor(with params as
    (select 'Param1' Code, 'string' DataType, 'Value1' Value from dual
      union all
     select 'Param2', 'int', 'Value2' from dual)
    select * from params)) as "params")
```

I can replace cursors with `ora:view` later if needed

Comment: But `XMLTable` does the reverse thing: it transforms XML to rows. Please, provide sample data from which you want to generate the above XML

Comment: In `passing` I provided all 3 sample parameters: service name, namespaces as `XMLType` and service parameters as `XMLType` for ease of testing. This query should compile right after the replacement ???. I do not know how to provide the stored data in another way